# Gutenberg breaks svg on save

Tags: reactjs, svg, wordpress-gutenberg

It seems that Gutenberg breaks SVG output in a block, but only for multi-word SVG attributes and only on save. Editor preview works fine.

I've encountered this on a more complex example, of course, but here is the simplest possible way to recreate:

If you add SVG to your `edit` and `save` functions with JSX:

```
<svg strokeLinecap={"round"}/>
```

The editor preview output is fine:

```
<svg stroke-linecap="round"></svg>
```

but `save` does something special to it:

```
<svg strokelinecap="round"></svg>
```

It looses the hyphen between words and therefore breaks all multi-word attributes. Browsers then simply ignore them.

Is this a known issue? Is there a bug ticket for this in Gutenberg? Is there a workaround? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've found that if you output SVG without the style tag, or convert the style tag to React style formatting, then it works.

Comment: Yeah I am seeing this too. Editor is fine, save is not. Gutenberg sure is a disaster. Using the WordPress components version per niklas Answer does not work either. I have no style tags or style attributes per cngodles comment. I think I'm going to check how the save output looks in the wp_posts table...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in June 2021. @niklas answer does not work, and @cngodles answer does not apply in my case and the issue remains.

Since the question asked if this was a known issue and if there was a bug report, I will answer that I found the following recent open issue and added a comment to it:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/30241

To hopefully help others: if you come across this SO hoping to find a solution or workaround, I think that your answer may lie with WordPress' extensive ability to modify behaviour with filters.

You can always filter `the_content` to find/replace erroneous attributes with valid ones. There are also a number of filter options specifically related to blocks: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/ and there is the ability to hook onto the 'save' action of a block in JS.

**Edit:**

Here is a quick example of a workaround accomplished with a filter where only the invalid `clipRule`, `fillRule`, and `viewBox` mappings are corrected. Add your own rules as necessary to fix your SVG's:

```php
    public function fix_invalid_svg_attributes_filter( $block_content, $block ) {
        $replacement = str_replace('cliprule=', 'clip-rule=', $block_content);
        $replacement = str_replace('fillrule=', 'fill-rule=', $replacement);
        $replacement = str_replace('viewbox=', 'viewBox=', $replacement);
        return $replacement;
    }
```

To hook the filter on `render_block`:

```php
// e.g. adding in functions.php or a simple plugin
add_filter( 'render_block', 'fix_invalid_svg_attributes_filter', 10, 3 );

// e.g. adding in a class-based plugin where the above filter function is defined as a method of a public class:
\add_filter( 'render_block', [ $this, 'fix_invalid_svg_attributes_filter' ], 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the `render_block` filter to add the missing dash for those attributes and works now.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is use the wordpress gutenberg own [`SVG` Component](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/55cac4e3168158e5a4e90eb0366844a7b7744fa1/packages/components/src/primitives/svg/index.js)

```
import { G, Path, SVG, Rect, Polygon } from '@wordpress/components';
<svg strokeLinecap={ "round" }/>
```